# Difference between ReactDOM.render method and component render method in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am confused with this from documentation. The class component has already got render() and return. Why in the last code line, there has a ReactDom.render again?

```
class LoginControl extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this);
    this.handleLogoutClick = this.handleLogoutClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {isLoggedIn: false};
  }

  handleLoginClick() {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
  }

  handleLogoutClick() {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: false});
  }

  render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    let button;
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
    } else {
      button = <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
        {button}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <LoginControl />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You should [**read the docs**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html) about a package's functionality / usage before posting a question.... the component has a render for the individual component, what it looks like and how it behaves. `ReactDOM.render` is mounting your whole component tree into the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

### Component render

Returns a set of instructions for creating DOM.

### ReactDom.render method

The render method can be called the primary gateway between React and the DOM. it is used to inject our React code into the DOM.

check this [article](https://reacttraining.com/blog/mount-vs-render/).